# Looping through json data in express.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

Im trying to loop through a json file and pick out every episode, but I'm confused that my loop only output the first `current_episode`, much appreciated if anyone can check my problem!

```
app.get('/episodes', function(req, res){
    fs.readFile('channels.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        var jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
        for (var i=0; i<jsondata.channels.length; i++){
            var myChannel = jsondata.channels[i].current_episode;
            res.send(myChannel);
        }
    })
});
```

My json data:

```
{
  "total": 70,
  "request_uri": "\/channels\/",
  "channels": [
    {
      "channel_id": 42,
      "current_episode": [
        {
          "id": 126248,
          "title": "Spanarna",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "channel_id": 43,
      "current_episode": [
        {
          "id": 126255,
          "title": "Beck: I stormens \u00f6ga",
        }
      ]
    },
............
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`res.send` writes the data and ends the request.  Try this instead:

```
app.get('/episodes', function(req, res){
    fs.readFile('channels.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        var jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        for (var i=0; i<jsondata.channels.length; i++){
            var myChannel = jsondata.channels[i].current_episode;
            res.write(JSON.stringify(myChannel));
        }
        res.end();
    })
});
```

Comment: got error `TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer`

Comment: @nihulus If `myChannel` isn't a string you need to convert it to one.  Simplest would be `JSON.stringify(myChannel)`

Comment: @nihulus If `title` is a property of `current_episode`, that's how you'd do it.

Comment: @nihulus Then `current_episode` in this case must be `null`.  Log it to the console to help debug it.

Answer (score 2):

Try building a string of your episodes.

```
app.get('/episodes', function(req, res){
    fs.readFile('channels.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        var jsondata = JSON.parse(data),
            myChannel = [];
        for (var i=0; i<jsondata.channels.length; i++){
            myChannel.push( jsondata.channels[i].current_episode );
        }
        res.send( myChannel.join("\n") );
    })
});
```

Comment: i got a output all data is object [object object]

Comment: Oops, yea you'd need to do have another loop to loop over the current_episode since it's also an array based on your structure.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have res.send(myChannel) **inside** the loop. res.send is sending the first channel as it finds and ignores the next calls to res.send().

Instead of this you should concatenate all the channels into a string and issue a res.send(allChannels) **outside** the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I found was:

You could try the following, however it will also load all the keys into memory

```
Object.keys(o).forEach(function(key, index, originalObject) {
  var val = o[key];
  logic();
});
```

However since Object.keys is a native method it may allow for better optimisation.

Whilst this was the code I would have always done I found this here (slightly more transparent code) whilst checking if this was the most optimal way to do things: [Iterate over object keys in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440001/iterate-over-object-keys-in-node-js)

Answer (score -1):

```
function search_items( args ) { 
if ( args ) {       
    string = args.toLowerCase().replace(/"/g, "").replace(/'/g, "").split(" ");
    for ( var i=0, j=0; i<string.length; i++ ) {        
    (function(i){           

        vocabulary.findOne({word:string[i]}, function(error, search){ // find vocabulary info

        if ( !error && search ) {
j++;
        pages.findOne({voc_id:ObjectID(search._id)}, function(error, pages){ // find pages info

            if ( !error && pages ) {

            page_tokens.findOne({page_id:ObjectID(pages._id), voc_id:ObjectID(search._id)}, function(error, page_token){ // find page tokens info

                if ( !error && page_token ) {

                pos_tags.findOne({_id:ObjectID(page_token.pos_tag_id)}, function(error, pos_tag){ // find pos_tags info

                    if ( !error && pos_tag ) {

                    resultTotal.push({vocabulary:search.word, pages:{doc:pages.base_url+pages.path}, page_tokens:{sentence_number:page_token.sentance_number,token_position: page_token.token_position}, pos_tags: { tag:pos_tag.tag } });
                    j--;
                    console.log(j);
                    if ( j==0 ) {

                        res.json({success:resultTotal});

                    }

                    } else {
                    res.json({ error:true });                       
                    }           

                });

                } 

            });             
            }           
        });         
        }           
    });     
    })(i)       
    }
} 
}
```