# How to copy images having them renamed with a prefix?

Tags: gulp, gulp-rename

I have the following array in Gulp:

```
var imageFiles = {
    'bootstrap-fileinput': 'bower/bootstrap-fileinput/dist/img/*', 
    'some-other-thing':    'bower/some-other-thing/dist/img/*'
};
```

I can be restructured if needed, as long as there is a prefix and path for that prefix.

How do I make gulp copy my images to the single folder I want, but prefix each one with prefix from the array? Means:

> bower/bootstrap-fileinput/dist/img/arrow.jpg =>
>   /images/bootstrap-fileinput_arrow.jpg
>
> bower/some-other-thing/dist/img/arrow.jpg =>
>   /images/some-other-thing_arrow.jpg

27.08.14:
Do I understand correctly, that the task I described cannot be achieved using only one pipe? In the solution provided by @Doodlebot each file is piped independently and sequentially as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this using the gulp-rename plug-in:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    var imageFiles = {
        'bootstrap-fileinput': 'bower/bootstrap-fileinput/dist/img/*',
        'some-other-thing': 'bower/some-other-thing/dist/img/*'
    }

    Object.keys(imageFiles).forEach(function(key) {
        gulp.src(imageFiles[key])
        .pipe(rename({
            prefix: key
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('images/'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Just an FYI: in Node (and modern browsers), you can use `Object.keys(imageFiles).forEach(function(key) { … })` to iterate over the keys without worrying about `hasOwnProperty`.  [More info here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440001/iterate-over-object-keys-in-node-js)

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that the task I described cannot be achieved using only one pipe? In the solution you provided each file is piped independently and sequentially as I can see.

Comment: Yes, since each src has a different rename prefix. You could potentially merge the streams after the rename pipe and use a single dest pipe, but I'm not sure the added complexity would provide any benefits.