# How to iterate over an array of objects in the request body

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am sending an array of objects to the server (as below), the server must receive the objects and add them to the mongodb. I'm new to node.js, I usually deal with the keys inside the rcevived request body (req.body). But here, the keys are the objects. How can I iterate over them?

```
[
    {
        id: "1",
        Name: "John"
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        Name: "Mark"
    },
    {   
        id: "3",
        Name: "Domi"
    }  
]
```

Server Code:

```
server.get('/user', function (req, res, next) {
//iterate over the objects in req.body
});
```

When I want to send one object I can easily get the the request content by req.body.id and req.body.Name, so how to do it with multiple objects inside the request body?

Comment: Are you sure those outer `{}`s aren't a `[]`? It's probably an `Array`.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440001/iterate-over-object-keys-in-node-js

Comment: You have mentioned in title as `Array of objects`..but your code doesn't depicts the same..

Comment: @Jacob fixed for convenient understanding

Answer (score 4):

something like this:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

server.get('/user', function (req, res, next) {
   var data = req.body;

   data.forEach(function (item) {
       console.log(item.id);
       console.log(item.Name);
   });
});
```

Comment: What is app used for? 
I'm getting this exception: nodejs Object #<Object> has no method 'forEach'

Comment: I fixed the upper exception, now I have another exception: [TypeError: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined]

Comment: change `app` to `server`

Comment: that means data is undefined, because your request you are checking is a get request, you should change `server.get` to `server.post`